# Random Numbers of a column of a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I need to generate random numbers that are not in a column,
can you help me, please.
The table is MI_TABLA
And the column is MI_COLUMNA
very thankful,
Sergio

Comment: Are you looking for [**`dbms_random.value`**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_random.htm#TTPLP71247)?

Comment: "not in a column" ... "And the column is MI_COLUMNA"??? What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Unfortunately if you cannot explain your problem clearly you are unlikely to get a helpful answer. For future reference including sample data and expected output helps us to understand what you want.

Comment: Perfect friends, thank you very much for your quotations, I have a column with N numbers, then the idea is that every time I generate a number that is not found, and if it is null that gives me the number that corresponds, I imagined a while

Comment: I meant that it will show me numbers that are NOT in the column called "MI_COLUMNA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a lot of detail in your question, but this may help you down a path.

The select below gets a random value between 0 and 500. I put the round function in so that it's whole numbers.

```
select round(dbms_random.value(0,500)) val
from dual
where round(dbms_random.value(0,500)) not in (select MI_COLUMNA from MI_TABLA);
```

If the random number chooses a value that is in your column, it will not return anything. Therefor you may want to put it in a loop until you get a number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now that happens if you throw a number that exists in the table, you should only show as a result numbers that are not in this one.
I imagined it with a while

Comment: You can loop until you find your number. Here is an example.

DECLARE
generated_num number;
found number := 1;

BEGIN
WHILE found=1
LOOP
-- generate number
select round(dbms_random.value(0,500)) into generated_num
from dual;

-- exit loop when new number found
select count(*) into found from MI_TABLA where MI_COLUMNA = generated_num;

END LOOP;
END;

Comment: thansks you .... but...

ORA-06550: line 6, column 10:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMBER" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol "; was inserted before "NUMBER" to continue.

Script Terminated on line 13.

Comment: It worked for me. Did you make changes? Can you post your script?

Comment: only changes was MI_TABLA and MI_COLUMNA
DECLARE generated_num number;
 found number := 1;
  BEGIN 
  WHILE found=1 LOOP 
   generate number select round(dbms_random.value(0,500)) into generated_num from dual;
    exit loop when new number found select count(*) into found from LK_PRD_PRODUCTO_VERSION where COD_PRODUCTO = generated_num;
     END LOOP;
      END;

Comment: The comments need to have -- before them or be removed (-- generate number and -- exit loop when new number found)

Comment: thansk you so much

Answer (score 0):

SELECT to_number(to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'yyyymmddhh24missffffff'))  FROM DUAL

This is a long value but it does not generate duplicate number.

But it is not random number. You do not need to check if value exists

Comment: I need an integer between the range 1 .... 999999

Answer (score 0):

This is inefficient, but may introduce you to some concepts you'll need for your very odd requirement.

```
CREATE TABLE a_table (a_column NUMBER);

WITH params AS
       (SELECT 1 min_value,
               1000000 max_value
        FROM   DUAL),
     possible_values AS
       (SELECT ROWNUM + min_value - 1 a_value
        FROM   params
        CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= max_value - min_value + 1)
SELECT a_value
FROM   possible_values
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 'value in table'
          FROM   a_table
          WHERE  a_table.a_column = a_value)
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

What this does is let you specify a range of values you want for your table, since a "random number" can be of any size.  It then finds all the values in that range that *aren't* already in the table and then chooses one of them at random.

It will perform badly for tables that have lots of unused values in the range, but will do better for tables that have only a few unused values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your tips, but I already have the table created with a column with integers, now I have to create random numbers that are not in this column

Comment: The insert statement I provided will do that.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DMCLIENTE.RandomNumber
   RETURN NUMBER AS numero NUMBER;  BEGIN        numero :=0;
        while numero <> null loop
            SELECT R.COD_PRODUCTO INTO numero FROM (SELECT ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(10,500)) COD_PRODUCTO FROM DUAL)R      WHERE ROWNUM=1 AND R.COD_PRODUCTO NOT IN (SELECT V.COD_PRODUCTO FROM LK_PRD_PRODUCTO_VERSION V WHERE V.COD_PRODUCTO IS NOT NULL);     
       RETURN(numero); end loop; EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR EXCEPTION RANDOM'); RETURN (numero);  END

Comment: That's a different approach and that's fine.  The approach I provided (A) is pure SQL (no PL/SQL needed) and (B) will not degrade performance-wise as the table fills up.  Since your version just returns the number (doesn't add it to the table), I've removed the `INSERT INTO` from my answer.